# How to create a pop up box in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have created an action button in R for my shiny application as follows

```
actionButton("action", label = "Help")
```

This creates the button but i'm not sure how to output a pop up box with text when the user clicks the button. It will be much appreciated if someone can guide me on how to do this please.

Comment: Check out the modals section of the **shinyBS** demo: http://spark.rstudio.com/johnharrison/shinyBS-Demo/

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Dead link

Comment: Check this out, http://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Modals.html